# What does the pSurfaceFormats in vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR represent?

Tags: vulkan

According to [vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR), the parameters `pSurfaceFormats` is a pointer to an array of `VkSurfaceFormatKHR` structures. If `pSurfaceFormats` is NULL, then the number of format pairs supported for the given surface is returned in `pSurfaceFormatCount`. The number of format pairs supported will be greater than or equal to 1.

I have used the `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` function with `pSurfaceFormats` having NULL value to return an array called `surface_formats`. I did this using vulkan, a python wrapper of Vulkan.

```
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR = vkGetInstanceProcAddr(
    instance, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR")

surface_formats = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR (
    physicalDevice = physical_device,
    surface = surface )

for f in surface_formats:
    print('    format = ', f )
    print('    format.format = ', f.format )
    print('    format.colorSpace = ', f.colorSpace )
```

Below is a print out of the array `surface_formats`:

```
format =  <cdata 'struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR &' 0x1a76f60>
format.format =  44
format.colorSpace =  0
format =  <cdata 'struct VkSurfaceFormatKHR &' 0x1a76f68>
format.format =  50
format.colorSpace =  0
```

**My Questions:**

1. Why does the `surface_formats` array has two indices, and not just 1 index or more indices like 3, 4, 5, ...? What does the number of indices relate to? Example, is it related to the number of indices of `VkQueueFamilyProperties` in my physical device?
2. Does `VkColorSpaceKHR` (i.e. f.colorSpace) only return one outcome or a few possible outcome from its allowed values listed below? E.g. can it return `VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR` and `VK_COLOR_SPACE_DISPLAY_P3_NONLINEAR_EXT` instead of just `VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR`?

   typedef enum VkColorSpaceKHR {
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR = 0,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_DISPLAY_P3_NONLINEAR_EXT = 1000104001,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_EXTENDED_SRGB_LINEAR_EXT = 1000104002,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_DCI_P3_LINEAR_EXT = 1000104003,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_DCI_P3_NONLINEAR_EXT = 1000104004,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_BT709_LINEAR_EXT = 1000104005,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_BT709_NONLINEAR_EXT = 1000104006,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_BT2020_LINEAR_EXT = 1000104007,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_HDR10_ST2084_EXT = 1000104008,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_DOLBYVISION_EXT = 1000104009,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_HDR10_HLG_EXT = 1000104010,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_ADOBERGB_LINEAR_EXT = 1000104011,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_ADOBERGB_NONLINEAR_EXT = 1000104012,
       VK_COLOR_SPACE_PASS_THROUGH_EXT = 1000104013,
   } VkColorSpaceKHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format describes how the color channels are encoded into the memory, this includes how many bits per channel.

Colorspace describes the mapping from the encoded color to the actual linear sRGB color space which you want colors to be in for physically based stuff.

This isn't a set of flags but a value, if a format supports multiple color spaces then each pair needs a separate value in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I got your answer for my 2nd question (your para 2 & 3). I did not understand how your 1st para relates to my 1st question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "indices" there.

Comment: The indices refer to index representing the size of the array `surface_formats`. In my case, I found the size of `surface_formats` to be two. Therefore the print statement output twice the `.format` and `.colorSpace` values. I would like to know the meaning to the size of the array `surface_formats`. Also, why it did not have a size of 1 or 3, 4, 5, etc but 2. Is it related to the size of `VkQueueFamilyProperties`?

Comment: No that's unrelated, the size is literally how many different format/colorspace pairs the implementation supports for the surface. You then pick one and pass the values into VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR when creating the swapchain. The size of the array can be 1 up to 2688 (all possible formats times all possible color spaces). Though getting more than a handful is going to be very rare.

Comment: What/who determines the "how many different format/colorspace pairs the implementation supports for the surface"? Is it the GPU, monitor, platform, window managers like SDL/GLFW, or a mixture?

Comment: Most likely a combination of driver, GPU, connected display and OS' window compositor.